# How do I handle classes that reference each other?

Tags: c++, class

Here's the code:

```
class B
{
    A a;
};

class A
{
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error:

```
1>c:\mine\visual studio 2010 projects\myproj\compiled equivalent.cpp(7): 
  error C2079: 'B::a' uses undefined class 'A'
```

Comment: this is really really basic, and I'm not trying to be mean, but you should be able to figure this out with a little bit of searching.

Comment: Yes... How is that gonna work? `A myA; myA.b.a.b.a.b.a.b.a.b.a.b...`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

Comment: Forward declaration won't help him... Those classes recursively contain themselves

Comment: Your profanity here is not acceptable. This is a professional site, and we expect adult behavior and language here. Please remember that people visit this site who object to some types of language. We try to remain acceptable to all people who visit the site.

Answer (score 9):

You can't. Two classes cannot contain each other as members. Consider answering the question “What is the size of the type `A`?” Well `A` contains a `B`, so what is the size of `B`? Well `B` contains an `A`, so what is the size of `A`? Oh dear, we have an infinite loop. How would we possibly store this object in finite memory?

Perhaps a more appropriate structure would be to have one of the classes contain a pointer to the other type. The type that is pointed to can simply be forward declared before the pointer member is declared:

```
class A; // A is only declared here, so it is an incomplete type

class B
{
    A* a; // Here it is okay for A to be an incomplete type
};

class A
{
    B b;
};
```

Now the type `B` doesn't contain an `A`, it just contains a *pointer* to an `A`. There doesn't even have to be an `A` object for it to point to, so we've broken the infinite cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you ask for references between the classes, probably you come from Java, C# or similar background where one can only put references to objects inside other objects.

In C++ there is no such restriction: you are allowed to have one object's content completely nested inside another one. But for this to work you must provide the definition of the nested object beforehand. C++ needs this definition in order to compute the size and layout of the outer object. In order to escape from this nesting you need to place not the object itself but a [pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html) or [reference](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html) to it inside the outer object.

That being said,

```
// C#
class A
{
  int x;
  B b;
}
class B
{
  int y;
  A a;
}
```

becomes

```
// C++
class B; // tell the compiler that B is a class name
class A
{
  int x;
  B *pb; // the forward declaration above allows you to declare pointer to B here
};
class B
{
  int y;
  A *pa;
};
```

if you decide to use the pointer syntax.

What this allows is to have things like:

```
// C++ again
class C
{
  A a;
  B b;
  A *pa2;
};
```

which has memory layout in the form of:

C:
  <kbd><kbd><kbd>a.x</kbd><kbd>a.pb</kbd></kbd>
  <kbd><kbd>b.y</kbd><kbd>b.pa</kbd></kbd>
  <kbd>pa2</kbd></kbd>

which is not possible in Java/C#.

Comment: How do we do 1 to many here ? What if I wanted an array of B inside A?